# Выдвигаемое меню в android как в Youtube

Tags: android, youtube

Как сделать выдвигаемое меню в android как в приложении Youtube?

UPD
Я хочу самостоятельно сделать это меню, но не знаю с чего начать

Comment: можешь и самостоятельно написать, ну а подсмотреть можно в либе

Answer (score 1):

[Вот это?](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example&hl=ru)

Ссылка откуда можно стянуть [библиотеку](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

Answer (score 0):

Очень качественная библиотека
[SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)